# how do you initiate cropper to crop image in fengyuanchen cropper

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, crop

I am using the fengyuanchen cropper and am using the crop-avatar example and want to pre-load an image into the cropper on load ready for editing.
I.e an image which has already been uploaded to the server.

I have spent hours on this and got no where does anyone know how to do this?

https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/tree/master/examples/crop-avatar

Comment: I want to find a solution as well, the documentation does not explain anything!

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with pulling the base64 from the server and populating on load.

```
// Added a class or just load
var $image = $('.img-container > img');
```

Maybe I'm missing it but, I put the image in 2 spots on for view and one for crop.